# Rails - Include nested resource in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-resources

I know how to include nested resources in controller render like this:

```
render :json => @user, :include => {:profile}
```

My doubt is: is it possible to do this in models?

I tried many ways but it doesn't give me the user and his profile like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John',
    profile: {
        id: 64,
        status: 'active'
    }
}
```

I tried this in my model:

```
User.where(id: 1).includes(:profile)
```

And the output was:

```
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` IN (1)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "in models"? Show how you want to access it and how it isn't working. You can do an include :profile when you fetch the model like: User.where(name: 'John').includes(:profile).all This will make two queries, one for all users named "John" and another for all of their profile records.

Comment: Hi Sixty4Bit, I am trying to use "includes", but it is not working (even with your example). It only gives me the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Ignoring render. If you want to include associated models in a JSON output just call [to_json with include as an option][1].

**Edit two:** Based up our chat it looks like you're wanting to get to objects, not JSON data.

Using your example user record:

```
users = User.includes(:profile).where("YOUR CONDITIONS") 
users.each do |user|
  puts user.profile.status #or do something with your loop
end
```

Comment: Also, [`jbuilder`](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) is a great way to build very specific JSON options at the controller level.

Comment: My render is working perfectly, the problem is when I tried to access inside my model like this: User.includes(:profile).

Comment: Are you saying the includes doesn't work because you aren't getting data for `profile`, or is your JSON is returning in the incorrect format?

Comment: calling your render like I show in my answer should include both `user` and `profile` in a `JSON` response. `to_json` allows you include nested models.

Comment: I don't want to render, I need this data in my model to do other things. I am returning it just to debug the data.

Comment: I added more details to the answer to show what I mean.

Comment: OK. Now suppose I need to get the user status that is 'active' in this case, to perform something. How can I do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79358/discussion-between-creativereason-and-sergio-toledo).

Comment: Correct creative, I can get all users, iterate over them, and get what I want. Thanks.